# Anyone used Reveal JS with Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, reveal.js

I am facing issue with Reveal JS integrated with Angular component. Initialized after DOM processed but its showing nothing.

1. When to initialize the reveal library?
2. How to add dynamic slides?

Answer (score 4):

have you got the solution?
If it's not then I am attaching my working code below.
TS file
[image]
HTML File

[image]

package.json
[image]

angular.json
[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing screenshots of code, will check and let you know

Answer (score 1):

```js
// home.component.ts

import Reveal from "reveal.js";
import Markdown from 'reveal.js/plugin/markdown/markdown.esm.js';
import Highlight from 'reveal.js/plugin/highlight/highlight.esm.js';


//...
export class HomeComponent {
// ...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    Reveal.initialize(
      {
        plugins: [
          Markdown,
          Highlight,
        ]
      }
    );
  }

}
```

I can confirm code and syntax highlighting works like a charm in this way, though markdown slides not working.